# returning a variable without quotes in php

Tags: php

i wanted to output 2 variables set as arguments inside a function.

```
function aboutMe($somenam="rahul", $someplace="delhi")
    {return "$somenam $someplace";}
    echo "<br/>",aboutMe();
    echo "<br/>",aboutme("sachin");
```

i just wanted to know why it throws an error if i use `return $somenam $someplace;` whereas it outputs correctly if i use `return "$somenam $someplace";`.Why is the quotes needed, because in the following code, there is no quote after return and is working fine:

```
function func_having_static_var($x = NULL)
  {
 $var = 0;
    if ($x === NULL)
    { return $var; }
   // $var = $x;
  }
  echo func_having_static_var();
```

Comment: What error? That code is valid. Demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/y5EJfA

Comment: `return "$somenam $someplace";` is the same as `return $somename . ' ' . $someplace;`. The quotes are needed because without them, `return $somename $someplace;` is just a syntax error. You can always return an array as well, such as `return [$somenam, $someplace];`. You can read up on [variable expansion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) that happens in double quoted strings.

Answer (score 4):

Its not that the quotes are needed, its that `return` can only return one thing.

When you type `"$somenam $someplace"` you are creating *one* string object and returning it.  You could do the same if you did `return $somenam." ".$someplace;` (it is still one object).

`return $somenam $someplace;` is invalid syntax, because you are returning two objects.

`return` only takes one variable (the value to return), which is why `return $var` works.

See the [documentation on returning values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can only return one value from the function. So you need to concate both variable using `.` operator if you do not want to use quotes to combine them,

```
return $somenam." ".$someplace;
```

Comment: That's not what he asked?

Comment: Does not answer or explain the question OP asked.

Comment: Might be but at-least not incorrect to get downvote.